# String exist in javascript , JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please i have the following code

```
if(page.language() === 'FR' && /myid/.test(active.item)){

}
```

I confirm my page.language return FR . my active.item returns object below

```
li#myid.item.fr-hide, prevObject: _.fn.init[1], context: a.link.pjaxload]
```

I am trying to check if my condition above is true. However its always false despite the fact that the string exist in the object.

I tried

```
"myid".test(active.item)
```

and encountered not a function error.

I tried

```
active.item.indexOf("myid")
```

and encounter an error as well. Please how do i solve this ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What was the error in indexOf ?

Comment: `active.item` clearly isn't a string. It looks like a jQuery object. Why are you trying to apply regex to it?

Comment: `/topMenuBetaInterface/.test(active.item)` does not look correctly imo - thats why you get "not a function error"

Comment: Hi Sir, i want to check to see if my sub string exist and then perform some action. Thats why i use the test method above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like magus said above, active.item is a jQuery object. Below is what works for me

```
var $elementid = active.item.get(0).id;

if(active.item) {
   if(page.language() === 'FR' && /myid/i.test($elementid)){
    //My code
   }
}
```

Another issue i encounter was `var $elementid = active.item.get(0).id;` passed my element id value to `$elementid`. However

```
if(page.language() === 'FR' && /myid/i.test($active.item.get(0).id)){
        //My code
       }
```

The above failed and always return false. When i log `active.item.get(0).id` on the console, it turns out it returns an object not my id . This i am not sure though , looking for a better explanation as well.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `active.item` is not a string at all. So `/topMenuBetaInterface/.test(active.item)` will always be false.

It also explain why you get an error when you try `active.item.indexOf("topMenuBetaInterface")`. That because there's no `indexOf` function in `active.item`.

Comment: Its index an object sir.